# Why do abstract variables require type annotation in scala?

Tags: java, scala

When I have an abstract class with variables as below

```
abstract class Book {

  val id : Int
  val name : String
  val book : Long

}
```

Declaring them without the types as,

```
abstract class Book {

  val id 
  val name 
  val book 

}
```

Says, wrong value declaration. If methods can be declared without explicit type annotations.

```
abstract class Book {

  val id : Int
  val name : String
  val book : Long

  def aMethodWithNoTypeAnnotation

}
```

Why can't variables also work similarly? Is this for a limitation around the JVM?

Comment: Doesn't a method without explicit declaration use `Unit`?

Comment: Yes they do, my point was that type inference works for methods when they get implemented in concrete classes, then why not for variables?

Comment: @GreedyCoder There is no type inference here - `def aMethodWithNoTypeAnnotation` is identical to `def aMethodWithNoTypeAnnotation(): Unit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala does not have global type inference, only local type inference. The type of a `val` or `var` is inferred to be the type of the expression used to initialize it. Abstract `val`s and `var`s aren't initialized, so there is nothing to infer the type from.

If you don't specify the return type of an abstract method, it is implied to be `Unit`. There is no type inference here. But `Unit` makes no sense for a `val` or `var`: there can only ever be one value of type `Unit`, so why store it in a variable?